# Check if a point collides with a surface (pixel perfect) in pygame

Tags: python, collision-detection, pygame

I'm developing a game (a [missile command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_command) clone) where I need to check if a [`surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) (a building) collides with a `point` (a missile).

[image: screenshot missile command]

How can I check if a missile hits a building?

A [`Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) has the [`collidepoint`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.collidepoint) method, but I want it to be pixel perfect.

[image: scene] => using a `Rect` => [image: using rect] => but it should be pixel perfect => [image: want it pixel perfect]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`Mask`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) and use it's [`get_at`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#Mask.get_at) method.

> Returns nonzero if the bit at (x,y) is set.

Creating a mask is quite simple by calling [`pygame.mask.from_surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface)

> Returns a Mask from the given surface.
>   Makes the transparent parts of the Surface not set, and the opaque parts set.

---

So, given the following helper method for some vector math:

```
def sub(u, v):
  return [ u[i]-v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]
```

use the following code to check if a given point is inside a mask/surface:

```
# create mask from surface
mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(building.surface)

# translate the position of the missile,
# since the top left coordinate of the mask is always (0, 0)
rel_point = sub(missile.position, building.position)
try: 
    if mask.get_at(rel_point): 
        # point in mask
        do_something()
except IndexError: 
    pass
```